# does leaving the laptop cord in break the cord?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

i recently got a new cord for my laptop because the cord i had before broke.im not sure how it got messed up, but one moment it charged my laptop and the next moment it didn't. i then got a new cord. the new cord worked perfectly fine until now, and it has only been a month. the cord wont work unless i am pressing it into the socket, which i am currently doing. the only thing i can find in common with the cords is that i leave them plugged in 24/7.  my brother says that is the problem, but i do not think it is.any tips or hints? im going to use duct tape to keep the pressure on the cord till i can find a better solution(im also thinking it could be the hole i plug it into on the back of my computer, but im focusing on the other idea for now.if i wiggle the plug part in the socket of my computer it will stop charging unless im pressing it in or to the side) any help or ideas are appreciated. not sure if this will help but i use a gateway with windows vista. thanks

Comment: Wondering how that cord is related to the Shift and Return keys... ;-)

Comment: I was typing with one hand and was trying to type it before my battery died. Sorry if its a little sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible this isn't a cord problem, usually when this happens, the socket is either:

1. Not solded on the circuit board properly,
2. The socket broke off from the main circuit board by applying sideward pressure on the plug while it was plugged in,
3. The circuit board has been torn/broken by the same cause as the one in remark 2,
4. Molten by use of an excessive charger. (This happens A LOT with Acer Laptops)

Answer (score 0):

No, subjecting the cord to mechanical stress or excessive current are what can break it. This is usually not a problem unless you move the laptop around a lot, or use a brick too large for the cord.

Answer (score 0):

I've got several laptops that are plugged in nearly all the time for days, even weeks, at a time.  I have had to replace one cord because the converter was damaged (dropped).  My suspicion would be that you have damaged the receiving socket in the laptop itself if the solution is to hold the cord in place.